How to show other info from my file JSON using JavaScript to html
I had learn some fetch for get data from file JSON but I still confused about how to get other info by click image. I have file data JSON like this. This file contain name, image, url and brand of some product
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "panda",
      "brand": "blue",
      "jenis": "cool panda",
      "deskripsi": "cute panda",
      "image": "a8205ca774a533e0053e6fe969443510.jpg",
      "url": "http:\/\/localhost:5000\/images\/a8205ca774a533e0053e6fe969443510.jpg",
      "createdAt": "2024-11-28 03:34:22",
      "updatedAt": "2024-11-29 06:37:36"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "fox",
      "brand": "crowd",
      "jenis": "fox samurai",
      "deskripsi": "strongest samurai",
      "image": "c87dcede772ef2d0fbdd5ceb65237937.jpg",
      "url": "http:\/\/localhost:5000\/images\/c87dcede772ef2d0fbdd5ceb65237937.jpg",
      "createdAt": "2024-11-28 14:12:39",
      "updatedAt": "2024-11-29 06:39:41"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "panda",
      "brand": "digital",
      "jenis": "samurai",
      "deskripsi": "its panda samurai",
      "image": "167748215ed489e0f363d5be562026dd.jpg",
      "url": "http:\/\/localhost:5000\/images\/167748215ed489e0f363d5be562026dd.jpg",
      "createdAt": "2024-11-29 03:39:16",
      "updatedAt": "2024-11-29 06:38:10"
    }
  ]
}

I have Code JavaScript Like This to show card for image, name and button.
const data        = "../php/data.json";
const jenisList   = document.querySelector('.content');
var urlParams     = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var jenis         = urlParams.get("jenis");
const modalDetail = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-primary');

const getProducts = () => {
  fetch(data)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).then(responseJson => {
      if (jenis == null) {
        showProduct(responseJson.products);
      } else {
        jenisProduct(responseJson.products);
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

const showProduct = product => {
  jenisList.innerHTML = '';
  product.forEach(agen => {
    jenisList.innerHTML +=
      `<div class="product-list">
            <div class="flex-div">
            <a href="" class="foto-product"><img src="${agen.url}" class="product-img"></a>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <p>${agen.name}</p>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" 
                data-target="#movieDetailModal" data-imdbid="${agen.id}">Show Detail</a>
            </div>
        </div>`
  });
}

const jenisProduct = product => {
  jenisList.innerHTML = '';
  product.forEach(agen => {
    if (agen.jenis === jenis) {
      jenisList.innerHTML +=
        `<div class="product-list">
            <div class="flex-div">
            <a href="" class="foto-product"><img src="${agen.url}" class="product-img"></a>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <p>${agen.name}</p>
                </div>
                <a href="${agen.id}" class="btn btn-primary modal-detail-button" data-toggle="modal" 
                data-target="#movieDetailModal" data-imdbid="${agen.id}">Show Detail</a> 
            </div>
        </div>`
    }
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getProducts);

And i still confused how to get other data like id, name, image, url, brand, jenis, deskripsi from JSON that specific what image or what button I click and it will show other data from JSON?.
to get other data like id, name, image, url, brand, jenis, deskripsi from JSON that specific what image or what button I click and it will show other data from JSON. I just want to Learn about fetch

What is the issue with the code here? Is it not working as you'd expect? Please explain a bit more or maybe share the output!

The result of code is show a card-box with image, name and button which contain data from json. But I don't know how to show other data like "brand", "deskripsi"  and "createdAt" from JSON in some box-container if I click a image or button in card-box

Your code is fetching data correctly, but what exactly are you trying to get when clicking on the show details a tag?

maybe you want something like replacing your div.product-info with  <details class="product-info">                     <p>${agen.name}</p>                     <p>${agen.deskripsi}</p>                     <p>${agen.jenis}</p>                 </details>

In your question it looks as if you want to show more information than what's available in the JSON. Am I correct? If so, you need to make sure the JSON contains that information. In other words, the source of that data (an API?) should send more properties.

If you add an event handler for each of your <a> elements, then you can use the id stored in you data attribute to find the product entry  and display more info from your data.
See the added code in showProduct()
If you run the snippet in Full page mode, it is easier to see the data being displayed when you click on a "Show Detail".


const data        = "../php/data.json";
const jenisList   = document.querySelector('.content');
var urlParams     = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var jenis         = urlParams.get("jenis");
const modalDetail = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-primary');

const dataInternal = {
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "panda",
      "brand": "blue",
      "jenis": "cool panda",
      "deskripsi": "cute panda",
      "image": "a8205ca774a533e0053e6fe969443510.jpg",
      "url": "http:\/\/localhost:5000\/images\/a8205ca774a533e0053e6fe969443510.jpg",
      "createdAt": "2024-11-28 03:34:22",
      "updatedAt": "2024-11-29 06:37:36"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "fox",
      "brand": "crowd",
      "jenis": "fox samurai",
      "deskripsi": "strongest samurai",
      "image": "c87dcede772ef2d0fbdd5ceb65237937.jpg",
      "url": "http:\/\/localhost:5000\/images\/c87dcede772ef2d0fbdd5ceb65237937.jpg",
      "createdAt": "2024-11-28 14:12:39",
      "updatedAt": "2024-11-29 06:39:41"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "panda",
      "brand": "digital",
      "jenis": "samurai",
      "deskripsi": "its panda samurai",
      "image": "167748215ed489e0f363d5be562026dd.jpg",
      "url": "http:\/\/localhost:5000\/images\/167748215ed489e0f363d5be562026dd.jpg",
      "createdAt": "2024-11-29 03:39:16",
      "updatedAt": "2024-11-29 06:38:10"
    }
  ]
}


const getProducts = () => {
  // EDIT Added for demo, replaces the fetch() 
  showProduct( dataInternal.products );

  fetch(data)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).then(responseJson => {
      if (jenis == null) {
        showProduct(responseJson.products);
      } else {
        jenisProduct(responseJson.products);
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}


function showProduct( product ) {
  jenisList.innerHTML = '';
  product.forEach(agen => {
    jenisList.innerHTML +=
      `<div class="product-list">
            <div class="flex-div">
            <a href="" class="foto-product"><img src="${agen.url}" class="product-img"></a>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <p>${agen.name}</p>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#movieDetailModal" data-imdbid="${agen.id}">Show Detail</a>
            </div>
        </div>`
  });

  // EDIT Added for handling clicking on "Show Detail"
  for( let button of document.querySelectorAll("a.btn-primary") ) {
    button.addEventListener( "click", event => {
      let id = event.target.dataset.imdbid;
      for( let next of product ) {
        if( next.id == id )  document.querySelector("output").innerHTML += `<br>id: ${next.id}, name: ${next.name}, image: ${next.image}, url: ${next.url}, brand: ${next.brand}, jenis: ${next.jenis}, deskripsi: ${next.deskripsi}`;
      }
    } )
  }
}


function jenisProduct( product ) {
  jenisList.innerHTML = '';
  product.forEach(agen => {
    if (agen.jenis === jenis) {
      jenisList.innerHTML +=
        `<div class="product-list">
            <div class="flex-div">
            <a href="" class="foto-product"><img src="${agen.url}" class="product-img"></a>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <p>${agen.name}</p>
                </div>
                <a href="${agen.id}" class="btn btn-primary modal-detail-button" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#movieDetailModal" data-imdbid="${agen.id}">Show Detail</a>
            </div>
        </div>`
    }
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getProducts);
<div class="content">
</div>

<output></output>



